# Can Shannon-Wiener index be used for measuring temporal differences?

Tags: biostatistics, entropy, spatio-temporal, diversity

I understand the Shannon diversity index being used in spatial analysis when comparing multiple sites of measurement, but can it be used to measure abundances, richness, diversity, etc. on a temporal level? I haven't found much literature looking at data series of community ecology using it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! I am a little unclear on what you're asking, but it can be used over time e.g. calculate it over different points in time. I am not sure what you mean by _can it be used to measure abundances, richness_ - why would you use the Shannon diversity to measure this when you can calculate abundance and richness directly?

Comment: Thanks! And my bad with the wording. I meant more on the point that calculating richness and abundance go hand in hand with Shannon index. I’m trying to compare differences in biodiversity over years given impact of an environmental stressor rather than compare two separate environments. I wasn’t sure if using Shannon index would be an appropriate method in this case.

Comment: Yeah! I think it will be fine. Just something important to note, is that Shannon's $H$ is a non-linear (log-scale) metric, e.g. say you have $n$ equally abundant species. Then if you have another site with $2n$ equally abundant species, the metric does not double, but increased by $\log(n)$. If you use a Hill Number (e.g. see Hill's 'Diversity and Evenness paper from 1972), of which $N_1 = \exp(H)$, then it is a linear function.